# Filter Fullcalendar Scheduler Timeline view resources based on their extendedProps

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Is possible to hide Fullcalendar Scheduler Timeline View (using the following package @fullcalendar/resource-timeline) resources based on the resource metadata (i.e. extendedProps)?

I found that is possible to hide them if there is not events related with that resource (using the filterResourcesWithEvents property).

Comment: The only way to "hide" them is to remove them as far as I know (but obviously keep a reference in case you need to unhide again)

Answer (score 1):

I have my resources load by a function which filters the array by the category (in my case) and then just loads the resources that match the desired categories. My function looks like this:

```
    function fetchResources(callBack) {
        let filtered_resources = resources.filter(function (e) {
            return categories.includes(e.category);
        });
        callBack(filtered_resources);
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that those resources are dinamically refreshed using an external filter based on the resource metadata.